# How can I get latitude & longitude by using address from google geocode API in Configure.IT API flow

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, google-maps, configureit

How can I get latitude & longitude values by using address from below geocode API inside [Configure.IT](http://www.configure.it/platform/apibuilder/) API flow.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=XXXXX&key=XXXXX

In below flow chart, before insert customer data I need to fetch lat & lng values and store those values into customer table.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ConfigureIT provides **API Connector** block for connecting to external datasources and fetching data. You need to insert **API Connector** block before **INSERT_CUSTOMER_DATA** block.

Follow the steps and example screenshots given below :-

1) Add an input parameter for supplying address.

[image]

2) Save your changes and in next step double-click **API Connector** block, to add in to your API configuration flow chart.

[image]

3) In API Connector block configuration dialog, select **Custom** for **API Type**

[image]

4) And then enter "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json" in **API URL** field and in input parameters section add and input parameter, **address** and link it to API input Parameter(we added in step 1) address and then click **Save & Next** to proceed to next step.

[image]

5) Now you need to set up API output. Enter test input and then for getting whole result from google api in result select **Current Format**
 and for specific part of the response, select **Specific Result**

[image]

6) Save all your API changes and then **Execute** to check the result

[image]

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=&key=
You have to pass your Google service API key to above URL then you will get
the result in json format as:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Mumbai",
               "short_name" : "Mumbai",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "short_name" : "MH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "400093",
               "short_name" : "400093",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Udyog Sarathi, Mahakali Caves Road, Marol Industrial Area, Andheri East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400093, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 19.1254233,
               "lng" : 72.8665118
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 19.1267722802915,
                  "lng" : 72.86786078029151
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 19.1240743197085,
                  "lng" : 72.8651628197085
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ02N9eyPI5zsRMEB_9ivO_B0",
         "types" : [ "establishment", "point_of_interest" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

The geometry contains location as lat lon format.